# Find spanning tree by removing heaviest weight

Tags: spanning-trees

I need to design the following algorithm:

Given an undirected, simple, and connected graph $G=(V,E)$ and some positive weight function $w$. The algorithm needs to scan the edges from the heavier edge to the lightest; in each phase the algorithm removes the edge only if the graph remains connected after removal of the edge.

How to implement the code efficiently?
What is the complexity of the algorithm?
What is the complexity of the algorithm if the possible weights are in $\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\}$?
Would the algorithm generate *minimum* or *maximum* spanning tree? or neither?

I have tried Kruskal's algorithm with negative edges (multiply weights by $-1$), but it's concern about the vertex attachments

Would like some help to understand.
Thank you.

Comment: Did you try using a theorem similar to [Theorem 23.1 from CLRS](https://dahlan.unimal.ac.id/files/ebooks/2009%20Introduction%20to%20Algorithms%20Third%20Ed.pdf#page=647)?.